# Remover elementos fora do desvio padrão

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho o seguinte array `[123, 350, 3456, 98]` e preciso remover os itens fora do desvio padrão como nesse caso o **3456**. Eu já tenho o cálculo do desvio padrão conforme abaixo:

```
class Array
  def average
    return 0 unless self.size > 0
    self.sum / self.size
  end

  def deviation
    average = self.average
    sum = 0
    self.map { |ar| sum += ar - average }
    variance = sum / (self.size - 1)
    Math.sqrt(variance)
  end
end
```

E para obter o desvio basta executar: `[123, 350, 3456, 98].deviation # => 1.0`

Mas agora não sei como isso poderia me ajudar em remover o **3456**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue abaixo em funcionamento. Remove os valores do array que estão fora do desvio padrão:

**Adicionar métodos na classe Array**

```
class Array
  def average
    return 0 unless self.size > 0
    self.sum.to_f / self.size
  end

  def variance
    average = self.average
    sum = 0
    self.map { |ar| sum += (ar - average)**2 }
    sum / (self.size - 1)
  end

  def deviation
    Math.sqrt(self.variance)
  end
end
```

e depois para obter o resultado:

```
my_array = [123, 350, 3456, 98]
average = my_array.average
deviation = my_array.deviation
my_array.select{ |a| a.between?(average - deviation, average + deviation) }.average
```